# Why is Kafka not creating a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to start a Kafka server on an ec2 instance. I'm following this tutorial: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KerNf0NANMo&t=2025s&ab_channel=DarshilParmar)

These are the following commands I ran to set up my ec2 environment.

```
wget https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.6.1/kafka_2.13-3.6.1.tgz
tar xzf kafka_2.13-3.6.1.tgz

sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless
```

Followed all the steps in the video until [timestamp](https://youtu.be/KerNf0NANMo?t=1717)

1. Starting zookeeper
   `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`
2. To increase memory
   `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M"`
3. Starting Kafka server
   `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

Zookeeper and Kafka servers are both running however when I try to create a topic, it fails and gives  an error message

This is the error message I get when trying to create a topic

> Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics

This is the error which comes on repeatedly in kafka server

> Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
> Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is x ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check this question answers yours [Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535706/how-to-resolve-kafka-error-connection-to-node-0-could-not-be-established)

Comment: Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore, and Java 17 is supported, and probably wont start at all with 256M heap. I suggest following official documentation, or otherwise click through AWS console to use MSK offering